# What is an ordinary 2-form?

Tags: differential-forms

What is the difference between an ordinary 2-form and just a 2-form in general? Cant seem to find the definition for ordinary 2-form anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: If it helps, it was used in the following context: 'Since U(1) is abelian, for any U(1) line bundle L over M, ad(L) is the trivial bundle $M \times i \mathbb{R}$. So the curvature f of a connection d' is an ordinary 2-form.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally a connection and its curvature are *Lie algebra valued*  differential forms, a particular case of vector valued differential forms,see e.g.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_differential_form .
 For the Lie group $U(1)$ the Lie algebra is isomorphic to the real numbers so you get what they call an ordinary (real valued) differential form.

Comment: Ahh, okay so it just means real valued. Thankyou!!

Comment: Just to clarify an additional point, if say q is an ordinary k-form, then the covariant derivative d' (given locally as d'=d+A, where d is the exterior derivative and A is a local 1-form) would act on q simply by d'q=dq, as q is real valued. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, that's correct